# Where does the term "Ring" come from in Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, math-history

Group and Field make some sense to me, but I can't see why the structures that are closed under two binary operations would indicate "ring".

Comment: How do groups and fields make sense to you? For me, "groups" in everyday speaking means something like a "set", and a "field" is where corn is grown :)

Comment: See also [this question on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/117292/39640).

Comment: Thx all. The question linked to in the post did not pop up when I was entering my question.